# dc.js bubblechart colors scale is not working

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to set colors for bubblechart based on certain threshold of data, My data has a domain of 0 to 100. I want to show different colors for values 0-40 , 40-60, and > 60.

I tried the following with out luck

```
.colors(["#e57275", "#94dfeb","#f6df86"])
.colorDomain(function() {
    return ["Poor", "Average","Good"]
 })
 .colorAccessor(function(d) {

    if (d.value.performance < 40) {
      return "Poor";
    }
    if (d.value.performance >= 40 && d.value.performance < 60) {
      return "Average";
    }
    if (d.value.performance >= 60) {
      return "Good";
    }
 })
```

Here is the [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpgGFk9fxm4aq6XPaEpI?p=preview) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That looks reasonable, wonder why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign the colours directly...

```
  .colors(["#e57275", "#94dfeb","#f6df86"])
  .colorAccessor(function(d) {
    //  alert('Lets chec' + d.performance)
    if (d.value.performance < 40) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (d.value.performance >= 40 && d.value.performance < 60) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (d.value.performance >= 60) {
      return 2;
    }
  })
```